# My Facebook appears like mobile when I am using it from PC

Tags: facebook

See this photo , it appears like mobile when I am using it from PC

[image]

How can I restore it to default ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's how it's supposed to look on the desktop. As of today (March 9, 2014), [Facebook changed the design so it has less clutter and bigger photos](http://www.nbcnews.com/tech/social-media/facebook-redesign-features-less-clutter-bigger-photos-n46271).